# How to Move Xaxis along Y axis using AchartEngine Android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AchartEngine api v1.1.0 for rendering Bar chart, I need help if we can move the x-axis which is on the bottom of the screen to meet 0 on y-axis.

I have posted the code for reference of what I am doing.

```
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(painLevelSeries);
    // Adding Expense Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(painLocationSeries);
    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize painLevelSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer painLevelRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    painLevelRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 80, 80));
    painLevelRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    painLevelRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
    painLevelRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize painLocationSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer painLocationRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    painLocationRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
    painLocationRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    painLocationRenderer.setLineWidth(5);
    painLocationRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(false);
    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);      
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("Pain Management");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Pain Level Effectiveness");
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setYLabels(15);
    multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(expense, Color.parseColor("#FC1625"));
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(25);
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(15f);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(15f);
    multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#003300"));
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    multiRenderer.setInScroll(false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 10, 80, 15, 0 });
    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(.1);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0.0);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(10.0);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(-10.0);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(10.0);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(painLevelRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(painLocationRenderer);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(-45);
    RelativeLayout chartContainer = 
     (RelativeLayout)      findViewById(R.id.painLocationContents);
    chartContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    // Creating a Line Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView)   
    ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(),dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
    // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);!
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Thanks for all your help.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the axis by modifying the visible range this way:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
```

and similar to the Y axis.

Once you do the above, don't forget to call:

```
chartView.repaint();
```